# How to pick the next 10th of the month ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a date calculation problem, which is confusing my logic.

I have an application that accepts debit payments to a bank account, this charge must be generated at least three days before the day to be billed.

I need to pick up the next tenth day of the month, which may be the current month or the next month, depending on the current day.

For example, today is October 7, I need to get the next day 10, as long as starting today has an interval of three days, in this case I need to be returned October 10.

But if today is October 8, I need to pick up the next 10, in which case I need to be returned November 10.

What is the best solution to do this in Ruby?

Comment: "But if today is October 8, I need to pick up the next 10" -> do you mean "But if today is October 18, I need to pick up the next 10", i.e. a day > 10?

Comment: @koffeinfrei, no... I need 3 days interval before generate, so if today is october 08, I need november 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option:

```
def next_10th_deadline_from date
  deadline = Date.new(date.year, date.month, 10)
  deadline = deadline.next_month if (deadline - date) < 3
  deadline
end
```

---

Or if input string and output string:

```
def next_10th_deadline_from date
  date = Date.parse date
  deadline = Date.new(date.year, date.month, 10)
  deadline = deadline.next_month if (deadline - date) < 3
  deadline.to_s
end

next_10th_deadline_from '2018-12-07' #=> "2018-12-10"
next_10th_deadline_from '2018-12-08' #=> "2019-01-10"
```

---

To work `require 'date'`

Comment: I've completely forgotten about *next_month*. I'll leave my answer as is since otherwise it's too similar to yours.

Comment: @JohanWentholt, I came out with a method pretty close to yours, but you've been faster (got my up). So, I had to review the https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html for finding an alternative. ;)

Comment: The answer looks cleaner when removing the old code. I'd also remove the date parsing at the start and *to_s* at the end of the method. Furthermore the *to_i* call is unnecessary since a *Rational* can be compared with an *Integer* without issue. A clean answer is easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for suggest this
Is very useful and clean

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of a [lazy enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) in ruby to find the next valid day, starting today.

```
(Date.today..Date::Infinity.new)
  .lazy
  .find { |date| date.day == 7 }
  .next_day(3)
```

Comment: Pretty clean. However this answer is not complete since the the 8th, 9th and 10th should return the next month, not the current.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Thanks you're right, I misunderstood the question. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
def next_10th(date)
  year, month, day = date.year, date.month, date.day

  month += 1 if day > 7
  year += 1 if month > 12

  Date.new(year, (month - 1) % 12 + 1, 10)
end
```

```
next_10th(Date.new(2017, 11, 7)).to_s
#=> "2017-11-10"

next_10th(Date.new(2017, 11, 8)).to_s
#=> "2017-12-10"

next_10th(Date.new(2017, 11, 10)).to_s
#=> "2017-12-10"

next_10th(Date.new(2017, 12, 8)).to_s
#=> "2018-01-10"
```

Comment: Alternatively you could replace `(month - 1) % 12 + 1` with `month > 12 ? 1 : month`. Since I don't like having *if* statements in method call parameters I've chosen the former. This is however just personal preference.

Comment: This solved my problem and code is more clean than mine, thank you!

@Johan > thanks for suggest this